# How to create dynamic styled component?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, emotion

What I'm trying to achieve is something like this:

```
import styled from 'react-emotion'

const StyledComponent = styled(({tag}) => tag)`
    // some css styles
`
```

And use it like:

```
<StyledComponent tag=div"/>
<StyledComponent tag="p"/>
<StyledComponent tag="ul"/>
// etc
```

My expectation was that it should generate HTML as follows:

```
<div class="some-class"></div>
<p class="some-class"></p>
<ul class="some-class"></ul>
```

Actual output:

```
div
p
ul
```

My question is, can this be achieved or am I missing anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like I have figured out a solution to my problem. Sharing my answer for those who may run into the same problem.

I changed `StyledComponent` declaration to following:

```
import styled from 'react-emotion'

const StyledComponent = styled(({tag, children, ...props}) => React.createElement(tag, props, children))`
    // some css styles
`
```

This is working as expected.

If anyone has the better answers please do post. Thank you

Comment: I ended up using this
https://styled-components.com/docs/api#as-polymorphic-prop

Answer (score 2):

What worked form me was using the **"as" polymorphic prop** (https://styled-components.com/docs/api#as-polymorphic-prop):

```
const StyledComponent = styled.div``

type ComponentProps = {
  tag?: AnyStyledComponent
  children: React.ReactNode
}

const Component = ({ tag, children }: ComponentProps) => (
  <StyledComponent as={tag}>{children}</StyledComponent>
)
```

Declaring the styled component outside of the function component will spare us from console warnings such as this one: https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/3117

Answer (score 1):

You are using `react-emotion` in wrong way, please try this.

```
const StyledComponent = ({ tag, children, ...props }) => {
  const Container = styled(tag)`
    background-colo: red;
  `;
  return <Container {...props}>{children}</Container>;
};
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/lr4xxp3757

Comment: Tried, but it's returning nothing :(

Comment: @SanjayJoshi, I have updated the answer, please check and confirm

Comment: Not an ideal apporach. This will give a console warning of something like: `The component StyledComponent  with the id of "StyledComponent-sc-59aae0fc-14" has been created dynamically.
You may see this warning because you've called styled inside another component.
To resolve this only create new StyledComponents outside of any render method and function component. `

Essentially this discourages creating styled components inside a function component.